# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer - access canvas of each page and handle events

Tags: html, angular, pdf, html5-canvas, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

In my angular app I'm currently trying to access the canvas of each PDF page using `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`. Currently, I'm able to extract the canvases in the `onPagesLoaded` event method the library provides, like so:

```
    onPagesLoaded(event: PagesLoadedEvent) {
        this.canvas = this._document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
        if (this.canvas) {
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    
            if (this.ctx) {
                this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                this.handleCanvasEvent();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the canvas for each page seems to be so buried in the DOM tree that I can't really listen to the events I need to listen to such as `mousemove`, `mouseup` and `mousedown`. I need this to be possible as I want to be able to draw on the canvas of the page.

Anyone here with experience using this library and manipulating the canvas of the pages that could help me out?

Comment: @KJ I need to use the canvas to draw some rectangles and I don't need them to be recombined on the frontend. Ultimately,  my goal is letting the user draw rectangles on each PDF page and then extract the coordinates/size of said rectangles and then send this data to the backend so that they can add a text field in the corresponding position. I'm currently just exploring different approaches so I'm open to different opinions on this.